# Java MouseListener issue

Tags: java, mouselistener

I don't want to create anymore `JLabel` object. I want to use `addMouseListener` because this way too pratice. But If I use this mouse listener doesn't work. Why?

Working code:

```
JLabel lb = new JLabel("Label 1");
lb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.isShiftDown()){
                System.out.println("Click");
            }
        }
    });
```

Doesn't work:

```
add(new JLabel("Label1").addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.isShiftDown()){
                System.out.println("Click triggered");
            }
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 addMouseListener(...)
```

Returns `void` therefore you cannot use the result as an argument for an other method call.

Comment: For a lot of methods it would be nice if they would return `this` instead of `void`. But the design decision was made differently.